# Use decorator to add meta data to interface properties

Tags: typescript, interface, decorator

Is it possible to use decorators to mark certain properties of an interface with some custom info?

Best explained with an example:

**App state interface:**

```
export interface AppState {
    @persist userData: UserData,
    @persist selectedCompany: UserCompany,

    // userCompanies should not be persisted since they are always
    // fetched afresh from the server...
    userCompanies: UserCompany[]
}
```

**Method which persists all relevant state info:**

```
persistState(state) {
    let newState = {};

    Object.keys(state).forEach((key) => {
        if (state[key] is decorated with @persist) {
            newState[key] = state[key];
        }
    });

    // Persist newState...
}
```

Is this possible?
If so, I'd really appreciate some resources to point me in the right direction!
If not, are there any elegant alternatives?

Comment: No, you cannot use decorators on interfaces, as the [docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html): "Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for **class declarations and members**". Interfaces don't exist at runtime which is the reason you can't add decorators to them. You can change your interfaces to classes and then you'll be good to go

Comment: I thought so. My app state needs to be built of pure JS objects (redux) which is why I can't use classes for this...

Comment: Decorators are an *experimental* feature (at least wrt to ECMAScript). They are not part of ES7.

Comment: somebody need this feature too: [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6818#issuecomment-311903830)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Is it possible to use decorators to mark certain properties of an interface with some custom info

No. Interfaces cannot be used with decorators as decorators work on top of things that actually exist at runtime. (Interfaces are erased).

Comment: Is there any other way of adding metadata to interface properties?

Comment: make it a class

Comment: but the problem in a class, it requires a constructor

Comment: finally a well explained answer ;)

Comment: @basarat What about interfaces that extends classes? If `class A` defines property `@foo b: number = 0;` and `interface B extends A`, *and then* `class C implements B` but doesn't implement `b` with the `@foo` decorator, does it carry over?

Comment: @sshanzel How about an abstract class?